# how can we use UICollectionView without an UICollectionViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uicollectionview

Normaly, if we want to use `UICollectionView`, we must use an `UICollectionViewController`. But now I don't want, so how can I use `UICollectionView` without an `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: Check and get sample code, you'll understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289592/ios-add-a-collectionview-to-a-another-view-within-the-storyboard-ui-builder/14290127#14290127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can use a `UICollectionView` without an `UICollectionViewController`.

Just create a `UICollectionViewLayout` of your choice, and then call

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
```

to create a new instance of `UICollectionView`. Don't forget to set the delegate and datasource of the `UICollectionView` to your class, and implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I created a class called "nContent" that implement UICollectionView: @interface NContent : UICollectionView <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>. And I set Ncontent as custom class for my UICollectionView, but it still error with message: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. NContent's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super

Comment: There seems to be something messed up with your auto layout constraints. This has nothing to do with the `UICollectionView` itself.